# How to apply a lambda function of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which has columns `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'C'`. I'd like to apply a lambda function on columns `'A'` and `'B'`. I have the following code:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row['A'] + row['B'])
```

but it gives me an error saying that

```
('A', 'occurred at index A')
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Use `index=1`, but you should't be using `.apply` here to begin with. Just `df['A'] + df['B']`

Comment: my logic a bit more complex that a simple + I just use it here as an example.

Comment: Well what is the logic and the real problem? You'd be surprised how creative you can get to avoid `.apply(axis=1)`

Comment: Just to clarify, if your function is still something that can be expressed fairly easily, consider expressing it directly to the dataframe. For example, the vectorized calculation of your example above would be ```df['New'] = df['A'] + df['B']```

Comment: @H.Z. well, in general, you should strive to avoid `.apply`. Likely, there is a better way.